# Importing functions using Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, methods, react-functional-component

TLDR - what's the difference between these imports in ReactJs using Typescript:

```
setState1: (numbers: number[]) => void,
setState2: Function
```

Hi peeps, I've recently came across weird(for me) behaviour of importing functions using Typescript on React. To explain it better I'll just put sample code:

```
const FuncComp: React.FC = () => {
   const [state1, setState1] = useState<number[]>([]);
   const [state2, setState2] = useState<number[]>([]);

   const handleSettingState1 = () => {
       console.log("state1-",state1);
       setState1([...state1, 1]);
   }
   console.log("state1-",state1);

   const handleSettingState2 = () => {
       console.log("state2-",state2);
       setState1([...state2, 2]);
   }
   console.log("state2-",state2);

   const saveChanges = () => {
       saveHandler(
          saveFunc,
          setState1,
          setState2
       )
   }
....
}
```

both `handleSettingState1` and `handleSettingState2` are functions passed to and set from child components, `saveChanges` is onClick function of button inside `FuncComp` and `saveHandler` is imported from helper file and it looks like this:

```
export const saveHandler = (
    saveFunc: GqlMutationType,
    setState1: (numbers: number[]) => void,
    setState2: Function
) => {
    saveFunc()
        .then(() => {
            setState1([]);
            setState2([]);
        })
        .catch((err: AxiosError) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

**As you can see `setState1` and `setState2` are imported differently.**
Now the problem is that when I set both states through handlers -> perform save(it should clear both arrays in *then* callback) -> set another value, `state1` will be empty both inside and outside `handleSettingState1` scope, while `state2` will have old value inside `handleSettingState2` but empty inside the scope of the class.

I skipped implementation of `handleSettingState2` and `handleSettingState2` inside child component because I thought it's irrelevant but if it affects I can provide it too.

Comment: There are no imports here, these are just type definitions. Furthermore, the type definitions *and the whole of the type system* don't change any runtime behaviour. The two functions are identical, if you get different results, that's not because of the type definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the save handler like so.

```js
export const saveHandler = (
    saveFunc: GqlMutationType,
    cb: (data: any) => void
) => {
    saveFunc()
        .then(data => cb(data))
        .catch((err: AxiosError) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

Importing and calling the function

```
import { saveHandler } from './filename';
...
...
function saveFn() {}

saveHandler(saveFn, (data) => {
   setState([...data]);
})
```

Comment: Your syntax is invalid

Comment: Hi, could you kindly let me know where the mistake is. I just put in a snippet to show a way to have callback. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cb(data: any): void` is an invalid parameter declaration. It needs to be `cb: (data: any) => void`.

Comment: Updated the code @AluanHaddad kindly check.